# Prometheus alertmanager custom receiver

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-java

I'm currently trying to setup Prometheus and Alertmanager, the issue I have come to and haven't found solution yet, is that I want alert to be send to our custom application with oauth2 authorization.

Is there any way how to build/configure own reciever ?

Let's assume that alerts have to be sent to url https://reciever.com/pm-alert/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you will need to use the [webhook receiver](https://prometheus.io/docs/operating/integrations/#alertmanager-webhook-receiver), and implement a daemon that can take in the webhook notifications and convert them to a format that your custom application can handle.